# Add pipe delimiter at the end of each row using unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, winscp

I am new to unix commands, please forgive if i am not using correct line of code below.

I have files (xxxx.txt.date) on winscp with header and footer. Now i want to add N number of pipe (|) at the end of the each row of all files starting from 2nd line till second last line. (i dont want | in header as well as footer).

Now i have created a scirpt in which i am using below command:

```
sed  -e "2,\$s/$/|/" $file | column -t
```

`2,$s/$/|/: adds | at the end of every line from line 2`
Now below are the issues i am facing

First

- The data doesn't change in the files i am able to see pipe added at end of each row in hive, how can i change data in files?
- I don't want | in footer.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: i am able to move data into file like sed  -e "2,\$s/$/|/" $file $updated_file  no i just want to remove | from footer

Comment: who ever put it down means they dont want any developer who is just starting coding on something new won't do that is it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to append just one "|" at the end of each line except header and footer

```
sed -i '1n; $n; s/$/|/' file_name
```

**1n; $n;** : Just print first and last line as is.
**-i** : make changes to the file instead of printing to STDOUT.

If you need to append n pipes at the end of each line except Header and Footer. If you use the below awk command, you will have to redirect the output to a temporary file and then rename it.

**Assumptions:**

1. I am assuming your Header and Footer are standard and start with some character(e.g., H, F, T etc) or String(Header, Footer, Trailer etc)
2. I am assuming your original file is delimited with "|". You can specify your actual delimiter in the below awk.

   *awk -F'|' -v n=7 '{if(/^Header|^Footer/) {print} else {end="";for (i=1;i<=n;i++) end=sprintf("%s%s", end, "|"); rec=sprintf("%s%s", $0, end); print rec}}' file_name*

**n**=number of times you want to repeat | at the end of each line.
**^Header|^Footer** - If the line starts with "Header" or "Footer", just print the record as it is. You can specify your header and footer strings from file.
**for loop** - prepares a string "end" which contains "|" n times.
**rec** - Contains concatenated string of entire record followed by end string

Comment: thanks for the reply.. one query | are also added in header and footer, so you just give and example for header and footer, also footer start with F| then number of rows and header contain columns names so could you please guide me how to print only header and footer ..